# Operator norm for non-trace class operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

While for trace class operators the Frobenius norm is useful. Is there any norm for operators that are not trace-class? 
Or is there any other concept that would allow to order such operators by "size" by means of assigning numbers?

Comment: Hilbert - Schmidt norm for Hilbert - Schmidt operators.

Comment: You can also look at the spectral radius, although it is not a norm and agrees with the operator norm for normal operators.